# Child Objects Not Following Parent Object On Frequent Teleportation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

[Game Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3o9p.png)

[Teleportation Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHZAe.png)

[Child Objects And Their Original Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZGnk.png)

I'm new to Unity, and so after taking just some regular online courses for Unity2D I wanted to mess around with adding in different features, the first of which I decided to do was something like in Portal, where a projectile spawns two connected portals you can teleport between. However, I've run into an issue. When I'm teleporting my character, sometimes, usually when I'm teleporting too quickly but can happen at any time, the child objects to the Player game object tend to shift, and I don't understand why. **I'd like to:

1. Know why the offset between the parent and child objects are changing through teleportation.
2. Know how to fix this issue, preferably in code I can easily understand as a beginner to Unity. Also preferably in a way that doesn't involve me constantly appending the child objects to the parent object through transform position with the added offset, though if it's the simplest solution I'm not against trying it.**

Something worth noting is that the offset change is different as well, I have a Child Object called Feet which detect the Ground for jumping, which seems to remain at the location of the previous portal when it first breaks. However, another child object called Gun which is where the projectiles spawn from seem to only move down a little bit, meaning there's inconsistency in how they are offset when they break. It might be because the Feet has a collider, but I'm unsure, don't know enough, and only felt it was worth mentioning.

```
[SerializeField] GameObject otherPortal;
    Portal otherPortalComponent;
    BoxCollider2D boxCollider2D;
    bool firstEntered = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        boxCollider2D = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        otherPortalComponent = otherPortal.GetComponent<Portal>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (boxCollider2D.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Player")) && firstEntered)
        {
            Teleport(collision.gameObject);
            otherPortalComponent.SetFirstEnteredFalse();
        }
    }

    private void Teleport(GameObject obj)
    {
        obj.transform.position = otherPortal.transform.GetChild(0).transform.position;
    }

    public void SetFirstEnteredFalse()
    {
        this.firstEntered = false;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        this.firstEntered = true;
    }
```

To simplify the question, the position of the child objects relative to the parent changes when I instantly change the parents position sometimes, why does this happen and how do I fix the issue without simply using transform.position in an Update method to constantly append the child to the parent, if possible.

Comment: no code images, post code itself please

Comment: To explain how the teleportation works, basically the portal checks for collision enter and sees if the colliding object is the player. If it is, and it's their first time entering the portal, it will change their transform.position to be equal to the Child (spawn point) of the other portal and changing the bool of the other portal to false so you don't get stuck in a teleportation loop. Essentially accomplishing teleportation.

Comment: Maybe collider colides with something and does not want to move.

Comment: It's not going to be possible to provide a good answer, both because the question lacks important details, and because the question itself is unfocused. That said, in general: "teleportation" is just a matter of updating the object's position; and, when dealing with parent/child relationships, the child's orientation and location state should always remain relative to the parent, meaning that you should _only_ need to update the parent's position, and the Unity3d framework will take care of the rest.

Comment: Assuming that you all mean my trigger Box Collider 2d for the Feet of the object is getting caught on something through teleportation, is that to say that transform.position doesn't instantly change the objects position but moves it towards said position in a fashion that seems instant?

Comment: @Grekys I don't know how colliders work internally but if only collider is being left behind that is probably the problem. Try disabling it and re enable after teleport. Or Make the player jump/go up first then teleport.

Comment: @Xentios It's not that the collider itself is left over, it is that the child objects offset itself changes, like it's position, because the Gun child object, which has no collider, also has a slight change in its position relative to the parent when the issue happens

Comment: I don't have an idea then. Do they have  transform or Rect transform?

Comment: @Xentios My bad, I went back to make sure and it does look like the only one moving is the Feet object, which does have the collider, however it is just the object itself that moves, and not the offset of the collider. I don't seem to understand why the Child object is getting caught, as it's set as a trigger, it shouldn't be making any physical contact with the ground or other object, just checking to see if you're touching them. I'll try testing to see if turning off the collider while teleporting works

Comment: Alright, I returned and tried it out. I will say that turning off the box collider and testing it to see if it would move seemed to show it staying in place. This implies the issue is indeed with the collider somehow. I tried disabling the collider before teleporting and then enabling it after, and it seemed to help a bit but still if you're teleporting too quickly it'll mess up. I'm still not sure why the collider is causing the child object to move when it  shouldn't make any type of collisions that would move a trigger collider. I'll try changing the execution of my scripts next.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your `OnTriggerEnter2D` method's if statement for a solution.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (boxCollider2D.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Player")) && firstEntered)
    {
        Teleport(collision.gameObject);
        otherPortalComponent.SetFirstEnteredFalse();
    }
}
```

Because you are using On**Trigger**Enter this method will only be called with your feet since your player's main collider isn't a Trigger. This means that your `collision` variable that you call your Teleport method on is actually your feet object, not your player's body object. So you are changing the offset of your feet from your player in your Teleport method.

I would try changing your collision method to [OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)
which would pick up your player's base collider when it enters and not the feet collider.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>() && firstEntered)
    {
        Teleport(collision.gameObject);
        otherPortalComponent.SetFirstEnteredFalse();
    }
}
```

Since the Player script is on the same object as your base player collider you can do a simple `GetComponent<Player>()` call to check if its the player object. Though you could still use the Layer to check if you want.